# nodejs with solandra connection

Tags: node.js, solandra

How to connect nodejs with solandra?

If it's possible provide some example code
I want to learn nodejs with solandra.

provide some sample code or some urls

Answer (score 0):

Since the Casandra side of Solandra is really just a rework for indexing purposes I'd expect that the Solr interface should still be in tact.

Therefore, you probably want to take a look at https://github.com/gsf/node-solr.